# Is there a way to find out the statistical power in python given two numpy generated distributions?

Tags: statistical-significance, normal-distribution, statistical-power, ab-test

I have 2 numpy distributions generated with this simple code

```
dist_a = np.random.normal(mean_a,std_a,1000000)
dist_b = np.random.normal(mean_b,std_b,1000000)
```

The first one represents the distribution of the control sample mean and the second one - the distribution of the treatment sample mean. The population mean and standard deviation for both control and treatment are known - I am just trying to run some simulations to see how the real statistical power differs from the estimated one if the real treatment population variance is either larger or smaller that the estimated one.

It's clear to me how to calculate statistical significance using these two distributions.

```
dist_diff = dist_b - dist_a
dist_diff[dist_diff > 0]
```

But it's not quite clear how I can possibly get statistical power using similar techniques.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: To compute the power you must have a test and an alternative hypothesis. Which test do you have in mind here?

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clear about the context. What I'm trying to achieve is to estimate the statistical power given the base mean and base standard deviation, along with the expected new mean and new standard deviation of the treatment. Sample size and desired statistical significance are known. That's why I generated the two distributions from the known population parameters.

Comment: Please, add any relevant information directly into and update your post. In the future, comments may be deleted. Furthermore, updating your post permits me to retract my downvote which, in light of your clarification comment, is not deserved anymore. But again, that clarification/information must go as a background in the post itself.

Comment: @utobi Thanks for your tip. Did that. I am still figuring out lots of things about A/B testing so my wording may be confusing at times.